# How do I import a trusted certificate into an existing keystore programmatically?

Tags: java, ssl, import, certificate, keystore

I need to import a trusted certificate into an already existing keystore, here is my code but its throwing me an EOFException, what could be wrong?

```
public void importTrustedCertificate( String alias, byte [] trustedCertificate )
        throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( "keystore" + File.separator + "ClientRegistrarKeyStore.jks" );
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( "keystore" + File.separator + "ClientRegistrarKeyStore.jks" );

        keyStore.load( fileInputStream, "keystore".toCharArray() );
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry( alias, new X509Certificate( trustedCertificate ) );

        keyStore.store( fileOutputStream, "keystore".toCharArray() );
        fileInputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        return;
    }
```

The Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:628)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
    at com.netrust.passportverification.clientregistrar.setup.IniFileGenerator.importTrustedCertificate(IniFileGenerator.java:107)
    at com.netrust.passportverification.clientregistrar.setup.IniFileGenerator.processZipFile(IniFileGenerator.java:165)
    at com.netrust.passportverification.clientregistrar.setup.IniFileGenerator.main(IniFileGenerator.java:180)

Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Cannot instantiate the type X509Certificates on line # 7

Comment: can you upload the complete code of creating a keystore and then importing a certificate into it? i have pfx certificate, can i import that certificate init? i am using android 2.3.3

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851341/load-ca-root-certificate-at-runtime-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the file at this location is not empty? Can `keytool` list its contents? This `EOFException` doesn't look specific to keystores, but it seems that the initial file you're trying to load from is shorter than it should be.

In addition, your `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` refer to the same file. I'd suggest closing the one your read from before writing to the other one, to avoid conflicts:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( "keystore" + File.separator + "ClientRegistrarKeyStore.jks" );
keyStore.load( fileInputStream, "keystore".toCharArray() );
fileInputStream.close();
keyStore.setCertificateEntry( alias, new X509Certificate( trustedCertificate ) );

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( "keystore" + File.separator + "ClientRegistrarKeyStore.jks" );
keyStore.store( fileOutputStream, "keystore".toCharArray() );
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: seems like closing one before opening the other stream works, thanks, how did you know they would conflict?

Comment: Cannot instantiate the type X509Certificate on following line `keyStore.setCertificateEntry( alias, new X509Certificate( trustedCertificate ) );`

Comment: can you help me in creating a keystore and then importing a certificate into it? i have pfx certificate, can i import that certificate init? i am using android 2.3.3. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);

keyStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, certificate);